# Make React Component available as a Widget

Tags: reactjs

I have a complicated React app (includes authentication to render certain components, etc) and there is a particular component, a date picker, which I would like other users to embed on their website as a Widget a la Google maps (`<script src="my_widget"></script>`).

I am already successfully sharing it as an iFrame, but I would like to learn how to do it as a 'proper' widget. Most of the solutions I found on SO were not to my understanding capabilities, perhaps I am pointed to a more noob solution.

FYI, I am using the `create-react-app` boilerplate code to load the React app:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

Comment: you can check out Web Components, there is even an example on React website: https://reactjs.org/docs/web-components.html#using-react-in-your-web-components
spec: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components

Answer (score 0):

You can create your react-app as it is. There are 2 more things that you'll need to make it work.

1. Provide a way to load or render your app on demand by the host page. For example rather than calling `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));` directly in the main app you can add a method like this:

```
const loadApp = (targetElement) => {
   ReactDOM.render(<App />, targetElement);
};
```

You can expose this method using a global variable like this.

```
window.reactWidget.load = loadApp;
```

2. After that you'll need to create a JS snippet, which can load your bundled javascript file and call this function once the file is loaded from the network.

```
 window.reactWidget.load(document.querySelector(#whatever'));
```

Comment: Hi thanks for taking the time to answer. Can you direct me to a working example to make sure I understand? What I cannot understand is how to render just one particular component as a widget rather than the whole app.

Comment: @5979642 I saw this comment today. Please find the demo here in case it is needed now
http://whack-chatbot.herokuapp.com/