# Make React components available to users as embeddable widgets

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, widget

On the [basketball-reference](https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2020.html) website, for the majority of the website's tables, there is the option **Embed this Table**, which allows users to generate a  tag that can be included in their own webpages.

[image]
.

I am working on a React (MERN stack) application, and I would like to implement this type of functionality. In particular, there are a handful of components (that return tables, graphs and charts) that I would like to make available to users of my website in a similar manner. For another example, [opta sports](https://www.optasports.com/services/widgets/) offers a feature for embeddable widgets that is similar to what I am seeking to build with React.

I don't know much about iFrames or about embedding apps into other apps. I'm not sure how to get started on this in React. Any thoughts or suggestions or links to helpful articles or libraries or approaches for this would be really helpful.

Thanks

Also: A similar version of my question was [asked previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57481789/make-react-component-available-as-a-widget), however the only submitted answer is not particularly helpful.

Comment: One thought is to use the react router to create routes that return only component X or component Y and then tell people to put iframes in their sites with `http://yoursiteurl.com/route` as the `src` where `route` is the special route where you are just showing the component in question.

Comment: why previous answer not helpful? some js file[-s] + div placeholder is the right way ... api for data/feeds, auth keys ... for live/frequently updated components/widgets ... SSR for prerendered, static (like gatsby) for including ... it all depends